# footer соц иконки в одну строку

Tags: css

Правильно я написала для футера html. Помогите застилить футер  и где найти информацию как это делать правильно.

```
<section class="footer">
      <footer class="footer">      
        <div class=" footer-logo text-center">
          <img src="img/logo-footer.png" alt="logo">
        </div>      
        <div class="container">
          <div class="footer-icon">
            <span class="footer-marker marker-black ">
           <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a> 
            </span>
          </div>
          <div class="footer-icon">
            <span class="marker marker-black ">
          <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a> 
            </span>
          </div>
          <div class="footer-icon">
            <span class="marker marker-black ">
              <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-behance"></i></a>
            </span>
          </div>
          <div class="footer-icon">
            <span class="marker marker-black ">
              <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i></a>
            </span>
          </div>
          <div class="footer-icon">
            <span class="marker marker-black ">
              <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-pinterest-square"></i></a> 
            </span>
          </div>
            <div class="container text-center">
              <h3>© Rhythm 2014 </h3>
            <p>Made with love for great people</p>
          </div>
        </div>   
    </footer>
</section>  
<!--FOOTER END-->
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а что у вас не получается ? хотелось бы увидеть проблему ... в чём она заключается ?

Answer (score 1):

Да там собственно делать то минуту делов ... только знать бы что надо

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  font-family: 'Times New Roman, Tahoma, serif';
  font-size: 18px;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.content {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}

footer {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  background: #fff;
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
}

footer a {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin: 8px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  color: #ccc;
  transition: all .3s linear;
}

footer a:hover {
  border-color: #222;
  color: #222;
}

footer a i {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.mountain {
  width: 60px;
  height: 20px;
  background: tomato;
  background: url(https://media.istockphoto.com/vectors/mountain-icons-and-symbols-vector-id165763529?k=6&m=165763529&s=612x612&w=0&h=STwcHEDryHu0UzMp7IPtOCVKpraffF5LlTubAPCmbxA=);
  background-position: ;
  background-size: 360px 150px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 80px;
}

.subfooter {
  text-align: center;
}

.subfooter p {
  color: #777;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="content">content</div>
  <footer>
    <div class="mountain"></div>

    <a href=""><i class="fa fa-odnoklassniki" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    <a href=""><i class="fa fa-vk" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    <a href=""><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    <a href=""><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    <a href=""><i class="fa fa-youtube" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
  </footer>
  <div class="subfooter">
    <p>&copy; copyright 2018 lensky</p>
    <p>made with love for a stranger girl</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Приглашаю Вас в SVG-чат, у нас там собирается хорошая компания, делимся советами, обсуждаем проблемы SVG и не только. https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70612/svg-chat